# Loading csv to table in Oracle

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, cx-oracle

I cannot get csv data into an Oracle table.

> ERROR:
>
> ```
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "H:/Standard_Procedures/Dataset_Management/Table_to_Oracle.py", line 139, in <module>
>       sde_cursor.execute(insert_string,row)
>     DatabaseError: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
> ```

CODE:

```
with open(dataset) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    column_string = ','.join(next(reader)).translate(None,'"')
    insert_string='INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ('.format(dataset_name, column_string)
    val_list=[]
    for i in range(1,len(first_row)+1):
        val_list.append(':'+ str(i))
    value_string=','.join(val_list)
    insert_string += value_string + ')'
    for row in reader:
        print 'Insert String = {}'.format(insert_string)
        print 'Row = {}'.format(row)
        sde_cursor.execute(insert_string,row)
```

PRINT RESULT:

Insert String = INSERT INTO area_harvest_summary_20170629a (PERIOD,YEAR,PERIODWIDTH,ObjectID,TSA_UKEY,POLY_NUM,CLUSTER,FMU,LANDBASE,WATERSHED,COMPARTMENT,OWNERSHIP,AREA,YC,Cover,AgeAtHarvest,HarvestYear,Treatment,NewYc,PriConifer,PriDecid,IncConifer,IncDecid,ConiferPieceSize,DecidPieceSize) VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15,:16,:17,:18,:19,:20,:21,:22,:23,:24,:25)

Row = ['1', '10', '10', 'A14029867', '7025115', '851840750', 'A14010716', 'A14', 'CON', '480', 'A14-A', 'Northlan', '9.022459984', '5', 'C_Mx_Sw', '118', '5', 'Inten', '5', '1718.527663', '0', '0', '598.0849757', '0.371338338', '0.287112087']

I have tried zip(row) and zip(row,val_list) but neither does it.Is it an issue with the string format of numbers in Row? If so, how do I get around this? I have also tried some of the methods I found on google, but again, no luck.

Ideally, I'd like this in an executemany statement, but all efforts on that side are as well not working.

Comment: From the error it would seem your SQL is incorrect. Perhaps try it in SQL*Plus first?

Answer (score 0):

You have reversed `VALUES` with enumeration of `rows`, change to the following:

```
with open(dataset) as f:
    ...
    # Don't change insert_string
    # insert_string += value_string + ')'
    for row in reader:
        # Append this row Data
        print 'Insert String = {}'.format(insert_string + row)
        sde_cursor.execute(insert_string + row)
```